# deploying rails app with rubber to AWS - nil:NilClass error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, rubber

I'm trying to use rubber to deploy to my AWS EC2 for the first time. For testing im just using a t1.micro right now.

I get a weird error with rubber after having edited rubber.yml after tcap rubber:create_staging

This is the message:

```
/Users/mgreschke/Dropbox/medisupply/vendor/bundle/gems/rubber-2.5.5/lib/rubber/environment.rb:1:in `expand_string': undefined method `known_roles' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/mgreschke/Dropbox/medisupply/vendor/bundle/gems/rubber-2.5.5/lib/rubber/environment.rb:168:in `eval'
    from /Users/mgreschke/Dropbox/medisupply/vendor/bundle/gems/rubber-2.5.5/lib/rubber/environment.rb:168:in `expand_string'
    from /Users/mgreschke/Dropbox/medisupply/vendor/bundle/gems/rubber-2.5.5/lib/rubber/environment.rb:180:in `expand'
    from /Users/mgreschke/Dropbox/medisupply/vendor/bundle/gems/rubber-2.5.5/lib/rubber/environment.rb:146:in `[]'
    from /Users/mgreschke/Dropbox/medisupply/vendor/bundle/gems/rubber-2.5.5/lib/rubber/environment.rb:230:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/mgreschke/Dropbox/medisupply/vendor/bundle/gems/rubber-2.5.5/lib/rubber/recipes/rubber/utils.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in load'
    from /Users/mgreschke/Dropbox/medisupply/vendor/bundle/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:138:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/mgreschke/Dropbox/medisupply/vendor/bundle/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:138:in `invoke_task_directly'
    from /Users/mgreschke/Dropbox/medisupply/vendor/bundle/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/callbacks.rb:25:in `invoke_task_directly_with_callbacks'
    from /Users/mgreschke/Dropbox/medisupply/vendor/bundle/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:89:in `execute_task'
    from /Users/mgreschke/Dropbox/medisupply/vendor/bundle/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/execution.rb:101:in `find_and_execute_task'
    from /Users/mgreschke/Dropbox/medisupply/vendor/bundle/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:46:in `block in execute_requested_actions'
    from /Users/mgreschke/Dropbox/medisupply/vendor/bundle/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:45:in `each'
    from /Users/mgreschke/Dropbox/medisupply/vendor/bundle/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:45:in `execute_requested_actions'
    from /Users/mgreschke/Dropbox/medisupply/vendor/bundle/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/cli/help.rb:19:in `execute_requested_actions_with_help'
    from /Users/mgreschke/Dropbox/medisupply/vendor/bundle/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:34:in `execute!'
    from /Users/mgreschke/Dropbox/medisupply/vendor/bundle/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:14:in `execute'
    from /Users/mgreschke/Dropbox/medisupply/vendor/bundle/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/bin/cap:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/mgreschke/Dropbox/medisupply/vendor/bundle/bin/cap:23:in `load'
    from /Users/mgreschke/Dropbox/medisupply/vendor/bundle/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'
```

Any idea where to look for an error? It seems like a simple problem to me but I dont really have a clue where to look..

Best,
M

Comment: look for a keyword `known_roles` in your whole app (possibly in your `environment.rb`) The object that is calling this method is returned as nil. If you can post some more detail on what object is calling it will be more helpful to debug.

Comment: Have you already resolved this issue? It would be helpful to publish solution.

Comment: Sergey, your post below and the link helped resolve the problem.Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just remove **rubber_env.**

```
staging_roles: "#{known_roles.reject {|r| r =~ /slave/ || r =~ /^db$/ }.join(',')}"
# instead of
staging_roles: "#{rubber_env.known_roles.reject {|r| r =~ /slave/ || r =~ /^db$/ }.join(',')}"
```

There is this simple fix https://github.com/rubber/rubber/pull/406/files.

Comment: Thanks Sergey. This fixed the issue for resolving app created for `complete_unicorn_nginx_postgresql` template